# ios Localizing MPMoviePlayerController Done button

Tags: ios, localization, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am writing an ios application for italy.

When i launch `MPMoviePlayerController`, there is a "Done" button on the top. I would like to change the Done button text to italian.

I changed `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to **`it`** and also changed the language of the simulator to italian, still the text of "Done" button is not changed.

What should i do to localize this Done Button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will be localized on the device, don't worry.

Comment: no its not working on device :(